# Binomial tree with jumps

Tags: binomial-tree, jump-diffusion

I am struggling with developing a binomial tree with jumps. although there are models such as CRR, could you suggest a book or have any idea to proceed?

Thanks, 
Amir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this paper (although it's advanced): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042702009032

The topic you picked is not necessarily an easy one :)

Comment: This paper quotes another paper K.I. Amin: *Jump diffusion option valuation in discrete time*, J. Finance, 48 (1993), pp. 1833-1863 which you might also need to look at to understand the basic method. Good luck.